# Electric potential - 2 power supplies

Tags: power-supply, power, energy

I'm studying among other things electrical engineering and I'm kind of in a discussion with a colleague about an 'experiment': he claims that when i measure the voltage between the + output of power supply number 1 and - contact of power supply number 2 the measured value is 0V. At first sight I would not disagree but I rather assume that the resulting voltage can be an arbitrary number, therefore 0V is a possible value. My argumentation describes that every contact of a power supply has an certain level of potential energy and therefore both contacts of the two power supplies can be on different energy levels and thus on various electrical potentials. Hence the voltage measured cannot be deterministically predicted.

Who is right?
Thanks

Comment: Neither is correct or both are correct, because it depends on what kind of power supplies they are and you never defined that. So it is unanswerable as it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is typically some non-infinite resistance between the probes of a multimeter or voltmeter. This can range from 100 k\$\Omega\$ for a cheap multimeter, to 10 M\$\Omega\$ for a professional model. As a result of this non-infinite resistance, in the absence of any sustained current through the voltmeter/multimeter, the two probes will equilibrate to the same potential, and the voltmeter/multimeter will display 0 V.

If the two probes of a voltmeter/multimeter are connected to two different DC isolated power supplies, and the voltmeter/multimeter is set to DC volts, then again, there is no closed circuit, hence no sustained current, hence the probes will equilibrate to the same potential, and the meter will display 0 V.

However, if the DC power supplies have **AC** leakage to the mains, as they often do, then the meter may close an **AC** circuit: mains -> PS1 -> meter -> PS2 -> mains. If the meter is set to AC volts, it will likely display some non-zero voltage. Depending upon the capacitance responsible for the AC leakage, this voltage might range from millivolts to surprisingly high "ghost" voltages.

I have assumed that the power supplies were DC isolated. However, if the power supplies share a common ground, then unless they are extremely resistant to accepting a few uA of reverse current, you will be able to measure the difference in their output voltages by probing their output terminals with a multimeter.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the reason no current is provided: "If the two probes of a voltmeter/multimeter are connected to two different DC isolated power supplies, and the voltmeter/multimeter is set to DC volts, then again, there is no closed circuit, hence no sustained current, hence the probes will equilibrate to the same potential, and the meter will display 0 V."

Comment: @olympus_mons A sustained current requires a closed circuit. That is a basic fact of electricity.

Comment: Ok, but why is there no closed circuit. My assumption is that, though the power supplies are two different 'systems' the 2 outputs are on some energy level and therefore it provides a voltage. So why shouldn't there result a current?

Comment: @olympus_mons To see why there is no (DC) closed circuit, ask yourself this. If current flowed from one PS through the voltmeter to the other PS, where would it flow to then? Somehow it needs to get back to its source, but there is no return path.